# custom user controller method not being called by strapi

Tags: node.js, koa, strapi

So i'm building a site backend for a project using strapi. A requirement for the site backend is there has to be a e-commerce component included since the client wants to do order processing, and process credit card transactions using stripe. With the that being said I decided to write a custom controller for user accounts that are created under the user-permissions plugin for strapi. This way I could link the user accounts from strapi to corresponding customer accounts on stripe's end.

However, i'm running into one problem in particular. The custom user controller methods I have written for creating and updating users seem to work as intended. Though whenever I delete users strapi doesn't seem to use the custom method I have written for deleting users at all. I even included a `console.log` call but nothing pops up.

I'm not really sure on how to go about fixing this issue since I can't see any of the log calls, and strapi doesn't seem to be spitting out any errors either when this occurs. Any advice on how to go about resolving this issue is appreciated.

Here's the custom controller i'm working on.

`<project_dir>/extensions/user-permissions/controllers/User.js`

```
'use strict';

/**
 * A set of functions called "actions" for `user`
 */

const _ = require('lodash'),
      { sanitizeEntity } = require('strapi-utils'),
      stripe = require('stripe')('<SK_HERE>'),
      sanitizeUser = (user) => sanitizeEntity(user, {model: strapi.query('user', 'users-permissions').model}),
      formatError = (error) => [{ messages: [{ id: error.id, message: error.message, field: error.field }] }];

module.exports = {
  async create(ctx) {
    const advanced = await strapi.store({
      environment: '',
      type: 'plugin',
      name: 'users-permissions',
      key: 'advanced'
    }).get();

    const { email, username, firstName, lastName, password, role } = ctx.request.body;

    if (!email) return ctx.badRequest('missing.email');
    if (!username) return ctx.badRequest('missing.username');
    if (!password) return ctx.badRequest('missing.password');
    if (!firstName) return ctx.badRequest('missing.firstName');
    if (!lastName) return ctx.badRequest('missing.lastName');

    const userWithSameUsername = await strapi
      .query('user', 'users-permissions')
      .findOne({ username });

    if (userWithSameUsername) {
      return ctx.badRequest(
        null,
        formatError({
          id: 'Auth.form.error.username.taken',
          message: 'Username already taken.',
          field: ['username'],
        })
      );
    }

    if (advanced.unique_email) {
      const userWithSameEmail = await strapi
        .query('user', 'users-permissions')
        .findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase() });

      if (userWithSameEmail) {
        return ctx.badRequest(
          null,

          formatError({
            id: 'Auth.form.error.email.taken',
            message: 'Email already taken.',
            field: ['email'],
          })
        );
      }
    }

    const user = {
      ...ctx.request.body,
      provider: 'local',
    };

    user.email = user.email.toLowerCase();

    if (!role) {
      const defaultRole = await strapi
        .query('role', 'users-permissions')
        .findOne({ type: advanced.default_role }, []);

      user.role = defaultRole.id;

    }

    try {
      const customer = await stripe.customers.create({name: `${firstName} ${lastName}`, email: email});

      user.stripeId = customer.id;
      
      const data = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.add(user);

      ctx.created(sanitizeUser(data));

    } catch (error) {
      ctx.badRequest(null, formatError(error));

    }

  },
  async update(ctx) {
    const advancedConfigs = await strapi.store({
      environment: '',
      type: 'plugin',
      name: 'users-permissions',
      key: 'advanced',
    }).get();

    const { id } = ctx.params;
    const { email, username, password, firstName, lastName} = ctx.request.body;

    const user = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.fetch({id});

    if (_.has(ctx.request.body, 'email') && !email) {
      return ctx.badRequest('email.notNull');
    }

    if (_.has(ctx.request.body, 'username') && !username) {
      return ctx.badRequest('username.notNull');
    }

    if (_.has(ctx.request.body, 'firstName') && !firstName) {
      return ctx.badRequest('firstName.notNull');
    }

    if (_.has(ctx.request.body, 'lastName') && !lastName) {
      return ctx.badRequest('lastName.notNull');
    }

    if (_.has(ctx.request.body, 'password') && !password && user.provider === 'local') {
      return ctx.badRequest('password.notNull');
    }

    if (_.has(ctx.request.body, 'username')) {
      const userWithSameUsername = await strapi
        .query('user', 'users-permissions')
        .findOne({ username });

      if (userWithSameUsername && userWithSameUsername.id != id) {
        return ctx.badRequest(
          null,
          formatError({
            id: 'Auth.form.error.username.taken',
            message: 'username.alreadyTaken.',
            field: ['username'],
          })
        );
      }
    }

    if (_.has(ctx.request.body, 'email') && advancedConfigs.unique_email) {
      const userWithSameEmail = await strapi
        .query('user', 'users-permissions')
        .findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase() });

      if (userWithSameEmail && userWithSameEmail.id != id) {
        return ctx.badRequest(
          null,
          formatError({
            id: 'Auth.form.error.email.taken',
            message: 'Email already taken',
            field: ['email'],
          })
        );
      }
      ctx.request.body.email = ctx.request.body.email.toLowerCase();
    }

    let updateData = {
      ...ctx.request.body,
    };

    if (_.has(ctx.request.body, 'password') && password === user.password) {
      delete updateData.password;
    }

    if(email != null || firstName != null || lastName != null) {
      let stripeUpdate = {};

      if(email != null && (email !== user.email)) stripeUpdate = {...stripeUpdate, email: email};
      if((firstName != null && (firstName !== user.firstName)) || (lastName != null && (lastName !== user.lastName))) stripeUpdate = {
        ...stripeUpdate,
        name: `${firstName != null && (firstName !== user.firstName) ? firstName : user.firstName} ${lastName != null && (lastName !== user.lastName) ? lastName : user.lastName}`
      };

      if(Object.keys(stripeUpdate).length > 0) {
        const customerUpdate = await stripe.customers.update(user.stripeId, stripeUpdate);

      }

    }

    const data = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.edit({ id }, updateData);

    ctx.send(sanitizeUser(data));
  },
  async destroy(ctx) {
    console.log('test...');
    const { id } = ctx.params,
          user = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.fetch({id}),
          customerDelete = await stripe.customers.del(user.stripeId),
          data = await strapi.plugins['users-permissions'].services.user.remove({id});

    ctx.send(sanitizeUser(data));

  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you activate the destroy action in user-permissions?

[image]

I've tested it with this simple `User.js` in `<project_dir>/extensions/user-permissions/controllers/`:

```
module.exports = {
    async find(ctx) {
        console.log('find!!!');

        return [];
    },
    async destroy(ctx) {
        console.log('destroy!!!');

        return [];
    },
}
```

`console.log('destroy!!!')` is called when I send a DELETE request to `http://localhost:1337/users/1234`